# Duplicate timestamps in timeseries - Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, time-series, cql3

I am going to use cassandra to store activity logs. I have something like this

```
CREATE TABLE general_actionlog (
   date text,
   time text,
   date_added timestamp,
   action text,
   PRIMARY KEY ((date,time),date_added)
);
```

I want to store all the activity in an hour in a single row (=a time serie. "time" is only the hour of the day in the format `H:00:00`, ignoring minutes and seconds, so I have a row for each `Y-m-d H:00:00`)

The problem appears when two actions happen in the same timestamp (ex. two page views in the same second), so the second one overwrites the first one.

How can I solve this in a way that I still can query using slices?

Thanks

marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `timeuuid` instead of `timestamp` for the `date_added` column.  A timeuuid is a v1 UUID.  It has a timestamp component (and is sorted by the timestamp), so it effectively provides a conflict-free timestamp.